# Rancher operation not permitted when I use mountPath

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, rancher

I am facing a problem when I am trying to deploy my docker imagene in Rancher using YAML.

This only happens when I decide to use a persistent volume, in case I don't use it, it works perfectly.

Here is the yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sonarqube-server-lte
  name: sonarqube-server-lte
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sonarqube-server-lte
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube-server-lte
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sonarqube-server-lte
          image: xictorlr/sonarqubemodificado2
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 1024Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 2000m
              memory: 2048Mi
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/data/"
            name: app-pvc
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
            protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: app-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonar-pvc-lte
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Best

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up your cluster?

Comment: Hi, the version of K8 is v1.19.12 and Rancher version is 2.5.5 rke cluster